# $\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$ $\Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})$ and $\Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{2n\mathbb{Z}})$ are isomorphic for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be odd. Show that:
>   $$\Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}) \cong \Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{2n\mathbb{Z}})$$

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$
My attempt:

An automorphism $f \in \Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})$ is uniquely represented by $f(1)$ since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}$. $f(1)$ has to be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/{2n\mathbb{Z}}$, which means $2n$ and $f(1)$ are relatively prime.

Thus, $\Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})^\times$ are actually isomorphic via the isomorphism $i \mapsto f_i$, where $f_i$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}$ having $f_i(1) = i$.

Since we can similarly deduce that $\Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{2n\mathbb{Z}}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/{2n\mathbb{Z}})^\times$, we have reduced the problem to showing that $$(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})^\times =
 (\mathbb{Z}/{2n\mathbb{Z}})^\times$$

Since $n$ and $2$ are relatively prime, we have:

$$\phi(2n) = \phi(2)\phi(n) = \phi(n)$$

Hence, both groups are of the same order, $\phi(n)$.

Now, I'm aware of the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/{p\mathbb{Z}})^\times$ is a cyclic group if $p$ is prime, but that is certainly not the case for $2n$, so we cannot easily conclude that they are isomorphic.

The only thing that comes to mind is to try to find what the elementary divisors for an Abelian group of order $\phi(n)$ could be. For example, $\phi(n)$ is even for $n \ge 3$ so there exists a unique element of order $2$ in both groups, which is $-1$. So the isomorphism would send $-1$ to $-1$.

How should I proceed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, then $\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}\Z/2n\Z$ is isomorphic to
$\Z/2\Z\times\Z/n\Z$. As $n$ is odd, any automorphism of
$\Z/2\Z\times\Z/n\Z$ preserves this factorization, so comes from an automorphism of $\Z/2\Z$ and one of $\Z/n\Z$. But $\Z/2$ has only the
trivial automorphism.

Comment: So, basically the argument goes like this$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$:
$$\Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{2n\mathbb{Z}}) \cong \Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}) \cong \Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}}) \times\Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}) 
 = \{0\} \times \Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}) \cong \Aut(\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}}) $$

I was not aware of the fact that $\Aut(H \times K) = \Aut H \times \Aut K$ when $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @mechanodroid That's because any element of order dividing $|H|$ must be mapped into $H$ by any automorphism of $H\times K$ etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** : by the CRT, $\mathbb{Z}/2n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic as *rings* for odd $n$, so their invertible groups are isomorphic. For rings $R_1, R_2$, what's $(R_1\times R_2)^\times$ ?

Comment: Ok, so basically this:
$$(\mathbb{Z}/{2n\mathbb{Z}})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}})^\times \times (\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})^\times   = \{1\} \times (\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/{n\mathbb{Z}})^\times$$

Comment: Yep that's exactly it !